# 'I believe I am ready'.

Tags: expression-choice

Is "I believe I am ready enough" the wrong way to say that I am ready enough?

I wish to write it with reasonable confidence that I am ready enough to take up a certain challenge. Is there another other way to convey the same?

Conversely - is "I believe I am ready enough" wrong way to say that I am ready enough?

Comment: Thanks guys. I am probably looking for correct grammar here. I should reword the question as is it grammatically correct to write  " I believe i am ready enough " ? Thanks for your replies any way. :)

Comment: Why vote down the question?  The OP is asking for correct grammar.

Comment: The question as redefined in the comment is a duplicate. Perhaps the downvoter thought it was too simple to be asked here. Stylewise, I'd rewrite, and could not improve on Neil's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

How about...

> I confidently believe I am ready enough.

Answer (score 0):

I am **prepared** for this new challenge